# Get user ID after logging in

Tags: login, cookies

I've been asked to add a sort of safety mechanism to a site where a user can only access their profile if they have a cookie set after logging in, and they can only have a maximum of 3 cookies. I've made a table in the database to store the cookies, so I can keep count of them.

I don't really know how WordPress works, but I've been able to find out that I need to edit the theme's `functions.php` file and add an action using `wp_login`. I've edited the `functions.php` file, added the action, request the user ID, and it returns `0`. I know that this is how `wp_get_current_user` is supposed to work, it returns `0` if there's no one logged in; however the user IS logged in, but it still won't return the ID. Here's the code:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'login_cookie' );
function login_cookie() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    //Get current user
    $id = $user->ID;

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['userCookie'])) {
        // Query the database to see how many cookies they have used
        $cookie_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_cookies WHERE user_id=".$id."");
        // If the returned value is bigger or equal to 3 than the user cannot login
        // they will be logged out, and redirected
        if($cookie_count >= 3) {
            wp_logout();   
            wp_redirect("");                
        }
        //Else they can login and they recieve a new cookie, which will get inserted into the database 
        else {
            $value = password_hash($id,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            setcookie('userCookie', $value, time()+360000*24*100, "", "",false);
            $wpdb->insert(
                "wp_cookies",
                [ 'user_id'=>$id, 'cookie_value'=>$value ],
                [ '%d', '%s' ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Also this should only affect normal users, not admins. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_login` hook provides access to two parameters: `$user->user_login` (string) and `$user` ( WP_User ). To pass them into your function you will need to add a priority (default is 10) and request 2 arguments from the add_action() call:

```
function login_cookie($user_login, $user) {
    global $wpdb;

    var_dump($user); // get WP_User object

    //Get current user ID
    $id = $user->ID;
    .....
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'login_cookie', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is now working as it was intented.

Comment: wc glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `wp_login` hook is passing the user object in its parameter.

```
function login_cookie( $user_login, $user ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID; // get user id
    // your next code
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'login_cookie', 10, 2 );
```