# Should `wp_login` be used since it's deprecated?

Tags: php, hooks, login, actions

I am working on a little script that requires the user role right after logging in. I Figured `wp_login()` would be perfect. I read this runs after the login of a user and contains 2 parameter of which one is the username. With the username I can figure out their role. But it seems `wp_login()` has been deprecated for quite a while now. I don't think `wp_signon()` can fill my needs in the same way `wp_login()` can. The question remains, should I use the `wp_login()` hook?

Comment: the function `wp_signon` does the same as the deprecated function `wp_login`, you just need to put username and password in an array :  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/

Comment: As seen in this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187705/get-user-id-after-logging-in you can easily grab the credentials. How do you get the credentials from the `wp_signon()` function? The question remains, should one use a deprecated function?

Comment: Don't miss that https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login/ and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login are not the same thing ! ;)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, where X is "how do I get the role of the user that's just logged in" and Y is the question above that tries to solve problem X. Have you considered asking about your original problem? I see no code in your question

Comment: @Jean-RémiLARCELET-PROST This was the entire problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't, it's deprecated

> I don't think wp_signon() can fill my needs in the same way wp_login() can

It does the exact same thing, but with a few new features

> I read this runs after the login of a user and contains 2 parameter of which one is the username. With the username I can figure out their role.

You still need that username to call `wp_login` in the first place, the primary difference with `wp_signon` is that it's passed inside a credentials array, rather than directly as a parameter.

If you had referred to the documentation, you'd have found a simple example taken from the codex:

```
$creds = array(
    'user_login'    => 'example',
    'user_password' => 'plaintextpw',
    'remember'      => true
);

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}
```

Also note:

> Note: wp_signon() doesn’t handle setting the current user. This means that if the function is called before the ‘init’ hook is fired, is_user_logged_in() will evaluate as false until that point. If is_user_logged_in() is needed in conjunction with wp_signon(), wp_set_current_user() should be called explicitly.

### A confusing point about your question

> The question remains, should I use the wp_login() hook?

`wp_login()` is not a hook, it's an actual function, and it's the function that is deprecated. The hook is not deprecated, and muddling the two is confusing

### Your Actual Question, and The One You Should Have Asked

> I have a script that I'd like to run when somebody logs in, how do I do this and how do I get the users role?

By specifically asking about your attempted solution, you've constrained and limited the number of answers you could have gotten.

For example, `wp_signon` is called by `wp_login`, and the `wp_login` hook is triggered by `wp_signon` too:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', function( $username, \WP_User $user) {
    // the user object has all the information you need, the username is probably not that useful. Anything you do via the username will just fetch the `$user` that you've just been given
}, 10, 2 );
```

Reading the documentation here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/

We see the following:

> Used By #Used By
>   wp-includes/user.php: wp_signon()

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer, I have made a mistake by mixing the function and hook together. If I didn't do that I didn't need to ask this question. I blame the fact that it is Friday. I feel sorry you spend time to create this answer on such a dumb and poorly formulated question. The code never was a problem, the question was: "Should I use a deprecated function?" and the answer is "No."